# Directory redirection issue with nginx set as reverse proxy

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-20.04

I have configured the server through Reverse Foloxy as follows:

Nginx reverse proxy(SSL Termination) - Varnish cache - Nginx web server(8080 port)

However, it has the following problems: For example, if you go to https://www.example.com/static (this is an example only, your domain is not my site), you will be redirected to http://www.example.com:8080/static/ . It is the same when accessing not only staic but also other directories. I am wondering how to do something like nginx.conf etc to solve this problem.

Comment: please share nginx.conf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
port_in_redirect off;
```

Nginx web server (8080 port) It was solved by adding the above setting to the corresponding server block.